# Can't see python libs inside Docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I want to build Docker container with python 3.6 and few dependencies.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM noondotcom/alpine-3.6-python-3.6-grpc

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3.6", "-m requests"]
```

**docker build -f Dockerfile .** executed without errors and I see all libs in *requirements.txt* are installed

But when I run **docker run** I got "No module named requests" message.

How I can fix that?

Comment: Have you tried going inside the container and see if your files are copied properly or not? `docker run -it <image-name>`. You may have to comment out the last line for debugging.

Comment: @HafizTemuri when I run your command I get python interpreter with all needed libs, so I can import and use them in REPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests library not have file `__main__.py`.
And need write `CMD ["python3.6", "-m", "requests"]`.

If package not have file `__main__.py` command `python -m <package>` didn't work

Comment: > Requests library not have file __main__.py. And need write CMD ["python3.6", "-m", "requests"].


it worked!
Thanks!
It looks like all worked since I built image, but checked wrong

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `CMD` statement in docker executes after the container has been built. That is the action your container is actually supposed to do.

You are getting that error because `requests` is not executable, since it has no main. `requests` is a library to be used by some python module after the statement `import requests`. Maybe your actual script should employ that.